# getting undefined control sequence error with subfig

Tags: subfloats

After loading packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
```

and attempting to execute:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfig[Something]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth{Figure_2a.pdf}       
\label{fig:2a}}
\subfig[Something_else]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{Figure_2b.pdf}\label{fig:2b}}
\caption{ Some rubbish.}
 \label{fig:2ab}
\end{figure}
```

I get an `Undefined control sequence error`, in spite of having no issues with the `subfig` package load. I found a similar problem on this forum which the user fixed by loading package `graphicx`, this won't apply in my case because `graphicx` is called.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should use `\subfloat`, not `\subfig`. And the `\label` for the subfloat should go *inside* the argument to `\subfloat`, not outside.

Comment: You're also missing a `]` after the first `0.45\textwidth`, and the `_` in the second caption causes an error of course. (@egreg It is inside.)